# how to write unit test case for following code snippet

Tags: javascript, ts-jest

```
export { className } from "path";  
export { className1} from "path";  
export { className2 } from "path";
export { className3 } from "path";
```

This file contains only the above lines, Should we write unit test cases for these kind of files, If yes,Please suggest how to write unit test cases for this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Maybe like -->
import { className } from 'path';

expect(className). toBeTruthy()

Comment: Thank you @HalilİbrahimÖzdoğan, is it correct to expect class name to be a boolean ?

Comment: I think, in this case, no needed unit test. If these lines removed, the code will crash. But if you want to check it, even so, it can be checked with `toBeTruthy`.

Comment: Got it @Halil İbrahim Özdoğan, thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to write tests for files that only exports something. If you have a `coverageThreshold` just ignore those files

```js
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  ...
  collectCoverage: true,
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    'path/to/collect/**',
    '!path/to/ignore/**',
  ],
  coverageThreshold: {
    global: {
      ...
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: Thanks @strdr4605, You mean to say in jest.config.js we have to give the ignore path file as my file, to avoid checking coverage for such files.